# Equivalent of Policy in ASP.NET Core MVC for MVC 5

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

Claims based authorization in ASP.NET Core MVC provides [Policy] methodology for the [Authorize] attribute.

Is there an equivalent way of achieving this in MVC 5?

Comment: Please be aware, that there is no MVC6.

Answer (score 2):

There is the project called [mvc5-authorization-policy](https://github.com/pschaeflein/mvc5-authorization-policy). Probably this is what you need.